# Infopath textbox displaying html tags

Tags: html, textbox, tags, infopath

How do I stop Infopath from displaying html tags in my text box? For example, my textbox has:

"Hello

World!"

but it will show up in the print preview as:
"hello
world!"

Strangely, Infopath is converting my text to include html..

Comment: you should rework your example - hello world looks about the same. Do you want to display html code within a textbox as rendered html code? i.e. `<b>` becomes **bold** test?

Comment: yep basically i want line breaks to actually BE line break :S

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a textbox to display HTML text as rendered HTML - you will need to use a rich text box.

You then would have to programatically add your HTML as child nodes to the text box like so:

```
MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("//my:rtfField", NamespaceManager).AppendChild("<h2 xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Header Text</h2><p xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">This is some paragraph text.</p>");
```

A good explanation of how to achieve what you want is here: [How to get HTML tags to appear as HTML and not as plain text in a Rich Text Box](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/how-to-render-html-in-rich-text-box-infopath.htm)

And some further links related to HTML + Textboxes: [Rich Text Boxes in InfoPath](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/use-rich-text-box-infopath.htm)

Comment: Sorry I am already usuing a rich text box. Im not writing html text in there to begin with, its putting html tags in when I do a print preview. Basically I want my line breaks to BE line breaks not <`b/>

Comment: From those articles I take it this should work with InfoPath Form Services (in the browser), but my RTF is coming up blank. It works just fine in preview. Am I missing something? The form is full trust and published through Central Admin.  Edit: on further investigation, HTML works fine, however I'm trying to add an iframe with the src pointing to a PDF in a document library on the same sharepoint site.. could this be a permission issue?