# InfoPath - Adding an iFrame into a Rich Text Field (web-enabled form)

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

This question [Infopath textbox displaying html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534621/infopath-textbox-displaying-html-tags) answers how to use an RTF in InfoPath to display HTML.  As far as [b] and [img] go it all seems to work fine, but any use of [iframe] only seems to work in InfoPath preview mode, and not in the InfoPath browser forms at all.  The RTF does not display the iframe and I can see no trace of it in the source of the page.  My goal is to display a PDF from a SharePoint list in an InfoPath browser form.

Is this possible in InfoPath web forms?

Answer (score 0):

From what i know, InfoPath Browser-Enabled Forms are very limited when it comes to RichTextBox's functionallity - only the OOTB tags (as given in the Toolbar) will work 100% correct.

I'm not sure if the ifram tag will work, but if it does, you'll have to code it like in [this article](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/how-to-render-html-in-rich-text-box-infopath.htm).

copypasted snippet:

```
MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("//my:rtfField", NamespaceManager).AppendChild("<h2 xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Header Text</h2><p xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">This is some paragraph text.</p>");
```

Comment: Yes, that is the example given in the article I linked, it doesn't appear to work.  It works fine while in preview mode within InfoPath, but nothing shows up in the actual browser.